# Assembly - I/O controller (Keyboard driver)

Tags: assembly

I read a book about Assembly. It gives example of a Keyboard I/O Driver:

```
section .data
ESC_KEY EQU 1BH         ; ASCII code for ESC key
KB_DATA  EQU 60H        ; 8255 port PA

section .text 
global _start
_start: 
key_up_loop:
    ;Loops until a key is pressed i.e., until PA7 = 0.
    ; PA7 = 1 if a key is up.
    in AL,  KB_DATA     ; read keyboard status & scan code
    test AL, 80H            ; PA7 = 0?
    jnz key_up_loop      ; if not, loop back
and AL,7FH      ; isolate the scan code

..Translate scan code to ASCII code in AL..

cmp AL,0        ; ASCII code of 0 => uninterested key
je key_down_loop

cmp AL,ESC_KEY  ; ESC key---terminate program
je done

display_ch:
     ; char is now in AL
..Print character AL to screen..
key_down_loop:
    in AL,KB_DATA       
    test AL, 80H        ; PA7 = 1?
    jz key_down_loop    ; if not, loop back

    mov AX,0C00H                   ; clear keyboard buffer
    int 21H                                ; (System interrupt)

    jmp key_up_loop
Done:
    mov AX,0C00H                   ; clear keyboard buffer
    int 21H           

..Exit Program..
```

I didn't understant the instruction: `test AL, 80H`, What Is purpose and how it check, by this way, that PA7=0?

**EDIT**: I also be happy for explanation about the `key_down_loop` section. Why we need that? we can to make the next change:

```
cmp AL,0        ; ASCII code of 0 => uninterested key
je key_up_loop
```

and then all the part of `key_down_loop` is useless. What i missed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `test` instruction does a logical `and` to the operands and sets the flags according to the result. The operands are not changed. A `test` instruction is to `and` what the `cmp` instruction it to `sub`.

For some strange reason, "let me google that for you" isn't allowed on stack overflow anymore (maybe to offending?), so the direct link: http://www.google.de/search?q=test+x86+instruction

PA7 is obviously bit 7 somewhere. I leave it up to you find out how that translates into `80H`.